# Understanding Structure Sharing in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

In the paper "Plugging a Space Leak with an Arrow" by Liu and Hudak, it is claimed that this leads to O(n^2) runtime behaviour (for computing the nth term):

```
 successors n = n : map (+1) (successors n)
```

, while this gives us linear time:

```
successors n = let ns = n : map (+1) ns
               in ns
```

. This statement is certainly correct, as I can verify it easily with GHCi. However, I can't seem to understand why exactly, and how structure sharing helps in this case. I even tried to write out both expansions for computing the third term.

Here is my try for the first variant:

```
successors 1 !! 2
(1 : (map (+1) (successors 1))) !! 2
     (map (+1) (successors 1)) !! 1
     (map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (successors 1))) !! 1
     2 : (map (+1) (map (+1) (successors 1))) !! 1
         (map (+1) (map (+1) (successors 1))) !! 0
         (map (+1) (map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (successors 1)))) !! 0
         (map (+1) (2 : map (+1) (map (+1) (successors 1)))) !! 0
         3 : map (+1) (map (+1) (map (+1) (successors 1))) !! 0
         3
```

and the second:

```
successors 1 !! 2
(let ns = 1 : map (+1) ns in ns) !! 2
(1 : map (+1) ns) !! 2
     map (+1) ns !! 1
     map (+1) (1 : map (+1) ns) !! 1
     2 : map (+1) (map (+1) ns) !! 1
         map (+1) (map (+1) ns) !! 0
         map (+1) (map (+1) (1 : map (+1) ns)) !! 0
         map (+1) (2 : map (+1) (map (+1) ns)) !! 0
         3 : map (+1) (map (+1) (map (+1) ns)) !! 0
         3
```

As you see, my expansions look almost exactly the same and seem to suggest quadratic behaviour for both. Somehow structure sharing sets in in the latter definition and reuses earlier results, but it looks magical. Can anyone elaborate?

Comment: You have to operate on graphs to understand sharing.  Doing it on linear formulas is confusing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To understand this, we need the definition of `map`

```
map _ []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

We will compute `successors 0`, pretending the spine of the resulting list is being forced as we compute it. We'll start by binding `n` to `0`.

```
successors 0 = let ns = 0 : map (+1) ns 
               in ns
```

Everywhere we hold on to the result of a computation - in a (non-strict) field of a constructor or a `let` or `where` binding, we are actually storing a thunk that will take on the value of the result of the computation when the thunk is evaluated. We can represent this placeholder in code by introducing a new variable name. For the eventual result of `map (+1) ns` being placed in the tail of the `:` constructor we'll introduce a new variable called `ns0`.

```
successors 0 = let ns = 0 : ns0 where ns0 = map (+1) ns 
               in ns
```

#### The first expansion

Now let's expand

```
map (+1) ns
```

Using the definition of `map`. We know from  the `let` binding we just wrote that:

```
ns = 0 : ns0 where ns0 = map (+1) ns
```

Therefore

```
map (+1) (0 : ns0) = 0 + 1 : map (+1) ns0
```

When the second item is forced we have:

```
successors 0 = let ns = 0 : ns0 where ns0 = 0 + 1 : map (+1) ns0
               in ns
```

We don't need the `ns` variable anymore, so we'll remove it to clean this up.

```
successors 0 = 0 : ns0 where ns0 = 0 + 1 : map (+1) ns0
```

We'll introduce new variable names `n1` and `ns1` for the computations `0 + 1` and  `map (+1) ns0`, the arguments to the rightmost `:` constructor.

```
successors 0 = 0 : ns0
                   where
                       ns0 = n1    : ns1
                       n1  = 0 + 1
                       ns1 =         map (+1) ns0
```

#### The second expansion

We expand `map (+1) ns0`.

```
map (+1) (n1 : ns1) = n1 + 1 : map (+1) ns1
```

After the third item in the list's spine (but not yet its value) is forced, we have:

```
successors 0 = 0 : ns0
                   where
                       ns0 = n1    : ns1
                       n1  = 0 + 1
                       ns1 =         n1 + 1 : map (+1) ns1
```

We don't need the `ns0` variable anymore, so we'll remove it to clean this up.

```
successors 0 = 0 : n1 : ns1
                   where
                       n1  = 0 + 1
                       ns1 = n1 + 1 : map (+1) ns1
```

We'll introduce new variable names `n2` and `ns2` for the computations `n1 + 1` and  `map (+1) ns1`, the arguments to the rightmost `:` constructor.

```
successors 0 = 0 : n1 : ns1
                   where
                       n1  = 0 + 1
                       ns1 = n2     : ns2
                       n2  = n1 + 1
                       ns2 =          map (+1) ns1
```

#### The third expansion

If we repeat the steps from the previous section again we have

```
successors 0 = 0 : n1 : n2 : ns2
                   where
                       n1  = 0 + 1
                       n2  = n1 + 1
                       ns2 = n3     : ns3
                       n3  = n2 + 1
                       ns3 =          map (+1) ns2
```

This is clearly growing linearly in the spine of the list and linearly in the thunks to calculate the values held in the list. As dfeuer describes, we are only ever dealing with the "little circular bit" at the *end* of the list.

If we force any of the values held in the list, all of the remaining thunks that refer to it will now refer to the already computed value. For example, if we force `n2 = n1 + 1` it will force `n1 = 0 + 1 = 1`, and `n2 = 1 + 1 = 2`. The list will look like

```
successors 0 = 0 : n1 : n2 : ns2
                   where
                       n1  = 1           -- just forced
                       n2  = 2           -- just forced
                       ns2 = n3     : ns3
                       n3  = n2 + 1
                       ns3 =          map (+1) ns2
```

And we've only done two additions. The additions to count up to 2 will never be done again because the result of the computation is shared. We can (for free) replace *all* of the `n1`s and `n2`s with the just computed values, and forget about those variable names.

```
successors 0 = 0 : 1 : 2 : ns2
                   where
                       ns2 = n3   : ns3
                       n3  = 2 + 1       -- n3 will reuse n2
                       ns3 =        map (+1) ns2
```

When `n3` is forced it will use the result of `n2` that is already known (`2`), and those first two additions will never be done again.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I understand it now!

Answer (score 13):

Loosely speaking: you are allowed to pretend, in the definition of `ns`, that `ns` has been evaluated completely. So what we actually get is, essentially,

```
successors n = let ns = n : map (+1) [n,n+1,n+2,n+3,n+4,...]
```

You only need to count the cost of this one `map`.

Let's think about this operationally.

```
ns = n : map (+1) ns
```

What does this *do*? Well, it allocates a bit of memory to hold `ns`, and stores in it a `(:)` constructor that points to the value `n` and to a "thunk" representing `map (+1) ns`. But that thunk represents `ns` as a pointer to that very same bit of memory holding `ns`! So we actually have a circular structure in memory. When we ask for the second element of `ns`, that thunk is forced. This involves accessing `ns`, but the portion accessed has already been calculated. It doesn't need to be calculated again. The effect of this forcing is to replace `map (+1) ns` with `n+1:map (+1) ns'`, where `ns'` is a pointer to the (now-known) second element of `ns`. So as we proceed, we build a list whose last piece is always a little circular bit.

Comment: Thank for your great answer too! It helped me a lot. Had a hard time picking which one to accept.